# Possible Memory Leak in Excel Macro to get info from large number of webpages

Tags: vba, excel, memory-leaks

I don't have much (or any) experience dealing with memory and memory leak problems, but it seems that's what is happening here.

I have an excel macro that has to
 - Follow hyperlink from a cell in the worksheet
 - Get Info from webpage
 - Do some string operations on info
 - Fill cells in the sheet with info obtained

My code is roughly:

```
Sub GetInfo()
    Dim numRow As Long
    numRow = Range("E2").Value

    Do While WorksheetFunction.IsText(Range("D" & numRow))
        If Not Range("D" & numRow).EntireRow.Hidden Then
            URL = Range("D" & numRow).Hyperlinks(1).Address

            Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
            IE.Visible = True
            IE.Navigate URL

            Do While IE.Busy
                Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
            Loop

            If IE.document.GetElementsByName("thing1").Length = 0 Then
                strFrame = "Unknown"
                strBasket = ""
                strBoxName = "Check Manually"
                strStartIt = ""
                strEndIt = ""

            Else

                strFruitwork = IE.document.GetElementsByName("thing1")(0).innerText

                If InStr(strFruitwork, "FRUITY") Then
                    strFruit = "Cherry"

                    numStart = InStr(strFruitwork, "ir:") + 3
                    numEnd = InStr(numStart, strFruitwork, " -")
                    strBasket = Mid(strFruitwork, numStart, numEnd - numStart)

                    numStart = InStr(strFruitwork, "ane:") + 4
                    numEnd = InStr(numStart, strFruitwork, " -")
                    strBoxName = Mid(strFruitwork, numStart, numEnd - numStart)

                    numStart = InStr(strFruitwork, "ey:") + 3
                    numEnd = Len(strFruitwork)
                    strStartIt = Mid(strFruitwork, numStart, numEnd - numStart)

                    strEndIt = "NA"

                Else
                    strFruit = "Berry"

                    allPropBoxes = IE.document.GetElementsByName("_.properties")
                    For PropBox = 0 To IE.document.GetElementsByName("_.properties").Length
                        strFruitInfo = IE.document.GetElementsByName("_.properties")(PropBox).innerText
                        If (InStr(strFruitInfo, "yaddayadda") <> 0) Then
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next

                    numStart = InStr(strFruitInfo, "Name:") + 11
            numEnd = InStr(numStart, strFruitInfo, Chr(10))
                    strBoxName = Mid(strFruitInfo, numStart, numEnd - numStart)

                    numStart = InStr(strFruitInfo, "BegNum:") + 15
                    numEnd = InStr(numStart, strFruitInfo, Chr(10))
                    strStartIt = Mid(strFruitInfo, numStart, numEnd - numStart)

                    numStart = InStr(strFruitInfo, "EndNum:") + 13
                    numEnd = InStr(numStart, strFruitInfo, Chr(10))
                    strEndIt = Mid(strFruitInfo, numStart, numEnd - numStart)

                    numStart = InStr(strFruitInfo, "Basket:") + 5
                    strBasket = Mid(strFruitInfo, numStart, Len(strFruitInfo) - numStart)

                End If

            End If

            Range("F" & numRow).Value = strFruit
            Range("G" & numRow).Value = strBasket
            Range("H" & numRow).Value = strBoxName
            Range("I" & numRow).Value = strStartIt
            Range("J" & numRow).Value = strEndIt


            IE.Quit
            Set IE = Nothing
            Set strFruit = Nothing
            Set strFruitwork = Nothing
            Set strBasket = Nothing
            Set strBoxName = Nothing
            Set strStartIt = Nothing
            Set strEndIt = Nothing
            Set numStart = Nothing
            Set numEnd = Nothing
            Set strFruitInfo = Nothing
            Set allPropBoxes = Nothing
            Set PropBox = Nothing
            Set URL = Nothing


        End If
        numRow = numRow + 1
    Loop


End Sub
```

I would *assume* the set = nothings should take care of the memory problem, but in actual practice, the script works for only 3-4 rows max at a time, before it gets stuck (the macro gets stuck at the point that the IE window opens up, but URL is not typed in/followed). Closing the IE Window manually, then starting script again makes it work fine, but again for just 3 lines. Given that my data is over 900(!) rows, you ca get why that's a problem.

Any help? (Please assume correctly that I know absolutely nothing about handling memory stuff)

Comment: Take the CreateObject statement out of the do-while loop. Initialize just one instance of IE and use this instance for all URLs. And IE.Quit and the Set IE = Nothing codes take out of the loop as well. So create instance of IE, use it in a loop, after the loop ends then quit the IE and set everything to Nothing.

Comment: @DanielDusek's suggestion (which echos the answer by asantaballa) makes a lot of sense. For debugging purposes, I would recommend taking "as much out of the inner loop" as possible. I suspect you are hanging in the "IE busy" loop - I would count the number of times you go around, and exit the loop after 10 seconds or so. This will distinguish between "out of memory" and "link not responding". If you change the URLs (start at a different place in your worksheet) does it still hang after three lines? In other words - is it the `3`, or is it the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a thought. I know would be lots of work, but consider doing a single

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

and then issuing multiple `IE.Navigate URL` for your lines. Opening the browser is a pretty heavy process compared to just going to an URL and may resolve/alleviate your problem.

Comment: This seems like an eminently sensible suggestion. It may not be the only problem, but this is good practice.